# Update multiple tables with one query

Tags: sql-server

Record to update

```
select *
from Event_Measurable em
join Observation_Measurable om on em.Event_GUID = om.Event_GUID
where observation_guid in (8786975, 285886, 85976, 786976)
```

Update these records as follows:

```
set observation_value_text = '.',    
observation_value_numeric = NULL,    
om.status = 'D',    
em.status = 'D',
```

I need help to update and set this values from the results of the query above. Can any help me. I have tried to update the table but it failed.

Comment: I recommend familiarising yourself with the `update` statement https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update  X   set
    observation_value_text = '.'    
,   observation_value_numeric = NULL
,   om.status = 'D'    
,   em.status = 'D'
from
(
select
*
from Event_Measurable em
join Observation_Measurable om on em.Event_GUID = om.Event_GUID
where observation_guid in (8786975, 285886, 85976, 786976)
) X
```

Let me know if it works?

Comment: Looking back at this, you might get an error stating that you cannot update more than one table. Please provide the column names in all the tables in your question?

Comment: Hello Birel, thanks for your help. The two columns to be updated are: Event_Measurable and Observation_Measurable

Comment: @Mekus, thanks, but these two columns, are they both in the same Table or in separate tables? If they are separate, I will have to alter my answer...

Comment: separate tables

Comment: Could you please specify which column is in which table? I will then alter my answer...

Comment: observation_value_text, Observation_Value_Numeric are in om table and while  status is in both em, and om tables

Answer (score 0):

Your `set` list references multiple tables: that is invalid as only one table can be updated with one statement. You need to run 2 `update` statements so you either repeat the `join` in the second `update` or first put the result in a temp table and `join` that to the actual to-be-updated table. You might want to put the whole thing to a transaction to be able to roll back on error. See [this reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/eab6e48d-d22a-4e1f-add6-aaf3b47bdd84/how-to-update-multiple-tables-in-sql-server-2008-?forum=transactsql).

Comment: Thanks, David, I will check out the reference provided